# Division of complex numbers in Python 3 class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, methods

I am having trouble creating a `__div__` method in a Python class for complex numbers which should divide two complex numbers.

Here is my code:

```
class Complex(object):
        def __init__(self, real = 0, imag = 0):
            self.real = real
            self.imag = imag

        def __str__(self):
            if self.imag > 0:
                return str(self.real) + "+" + str(self.imag) + "i"
            elif self.imag < 0:
                return str(self.real) + str(self.imag) + "i"

        def __div__(self, other):
            x = self.real * other.real + self.imag * other.imag
            y = self.imag * other.real - self.real * other.imag
            z = other.real**2 + other.imag**2
            real = x / z
            imag = y / z
            return Complex(real, imag)

no = Complex(2,-8)
no2 = Complex(3,7)
print(no/no2)
```

Unfortunately, my approach doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use Python's built-in complex type?

Comment: @JohnO Because I must use methods :)

Comment: Watch for div-by-0

Comment: @Eve you made mistake in calculation of real and imag part of resultant no it should be `x = self.real * other.real - self.imag * other.imag` and 
           `y = self.imag * other.real + self.real * other.imag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`__truediv__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), not `__div__`. `__div__` was the name for the old Python 2 "floordiv for integer, truediv for non-integer" division.

While you're fixing things, you should probably add an `else` case in `__str__`.

Answer (score 3):

`__div__` doesn't exist anymore in Python 3. It's been replaced by `__truediv__` for / and `__floordiv__` for //

Have a look at
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a method `__div__(self, other)` where you divide the no and also a new method `__opposite__(self)` to change the sign when multipy,
also calling method how to devide ie no/no1 is not a god method

using @johnO  solution, overwiting `__truediv__` 
so OP can use `no/no2` to division two complex numbers.

see code below

class Complex(object):
        def **init**(self, real = 0, imag = 0):
            self.real = real
            self.imag = imag

```
    def __str__(self):
        if self.imag > 0:
            return str(self.real) + "+" + str(self.imag) + "i"
        elif self.imag < 0:
            return str(self.real) + str(self.imag) + "i"
    def __opposite__(self):
        self.real =self.real
        self.imag = self. imag if self.imag<0 else self.imag * -1


    def __truediv__(self, other):
        other.__opposite__()



        x = self.real * other.real - self.imag * other.imag
        y = self.imag * other.real + self.real * other.imag
        z = other.real**2 + other.imag**2
        self.new_real = x / z
        self.new_imag = y / z
        if self.new_imag>0:
            result = "{} + {}i".format(self.new_real, self.new_imag)
        else:
            result = "{} {}i".format(self.new_real, self.new_imag)
        return result

no = Complex(4,5)
no2 = Complex(2,6)
print(no/no2)
```

output

```
0.24 + 0.68i
```

Comment: @Eve maybe this is what you are trying to do

Comment: Do you mean `__invert__` instead of `__opposite__`?

Comment: @NChauhan i forget to how to do complex no division, so [go thorugh this](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/complex/dividing/dividing_complex.html) and trusted Op calculation , `__opposite__` is just a function name that i given, it can be of anything

Comment: In that case, it is not advised to use double leading and trailing underscore names `__xxx__`. They are subject to change without notice. You should rename it to just `opposite`.

Comment: @NChauhan this just mean that this is private function and it will be used internally and don't require to be used as extenal function ,, in what you are saying i can change `__div__` to `division` but changing `__opposite__` to `opposite` is against the python  standards

Comment: `__div__` is a designated special method name called on the use of the division operation. `__opposite__` is not. Python has no ‘private’ functions, but generally you can use `_opposite` with a single underscore to indicate it is for internal use. There is no way to stop a user from calling it from the outside

Comment: @NChauhan `__div__` is used not more in python3, i changed my solution and used default `__truediv__` from JohnO solution, , you are true that in python there is no concept of private and public , but `_` and `__` methods are used to indicate other programmer not to use this part outside the class, though they are accsible, often given as warning my ide for developer for not to use them outside the class scope